# watermarked PasswordBox in winrt

Tags: windows-8, passwords, winrt-xaml

is it possible to get a watermarks passwordbox in WinRt? It is no problem to get a textbox with a watermark, but I don't know a toolkit where I can get a password box with a watermark.

How can I implement one for myself?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/).

They also have

1. WatermarkTextBox
2. WatermarkPasswordBox

By yourself you can implement your own controls:

in .xaml:

```
 <Border x:Name="brdPassword" Margin="5,0,5,10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Row="0"
                                Background="White" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                           <Grid>
                <TextBox x:Name="PasswordWatermark" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                          Text="Watermark"  Foreground="#FFC4C4C4" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                          Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0,-10" 
                          FontSize="26.667" />
                 <PasswordBox x:Name="pbPassword" LostFocus="PasswordLostFocus"
                         GotFocus="PasswordGotFocus" Background="{x:Null}" 
                         FontSize="26.667" Margin="0,-12,0,-9" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         BorderThickness="0" Opacity="0" />
                </Grid>
                </Border>
```

in .cs

```
    private void PasswordLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckPasswordWatermark();
    }

    private void CheckPasswordWatermark()
    {
        var passwordEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pbPassword.Password);
        PasswordWatermark.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 100 : 0;
        pbPassword.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 0 : 100;
    }

    private void PasswordGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordWatermark.Opacity = 0;
        pbPassword.Opacity = 100;
    }
```

Hope it's help

Comment: Looks like what he wants. Good post.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT, I have question for you. May be here I need to change visibility (not opacity), because when opacity == 0, control still detect events and participates in the tab order?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can put watermark in the Password control.
You can put a TextBox with wartermark in the same row and same column with the Password control, then handle the two controls' GotFocus and LostFocus events to make the control Visible or Collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no toolkit yet which provides watermarked password box. However this may help:-

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Watermarked-TextBox-and-444ebdec

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=300 for both a Textbox and PasswordBox implementation for WinRT.