# How can I add WaterMark property to PasswordBox in Winrt?

Tags: textbox, windows-runtime, watermark, maskedtextbox, passwordbox

I need WatermarkPasswordBox control but there is not in Winrt. Maybe we can add Watermark property to PasswordBox. Are there anyone who can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

If you don't want to use 3rd party DLL, add these two methods in `PasswordBoxBehavior.cs` file.

```
using System.Reflection;

public static T FindVisualChildByName<T>(this DependencyObject fe, string name) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(fe); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(fe, i);
        string a = child.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty) as string;
        if (a == name)
        {
            return child as T;
        }
        T t = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name);
        if (t != null)
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}

public static T FindVisualParent<T>(this DependencyObject fe) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (fe = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(fe); fe != null; fe = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(fe))
    {
        T t = fe as T;
        if (t != null)
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

---

Here's extensive blog from JulMar

[Adding a watermark to a PasswordBox in a Windows Store app](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=300)

[Here’s the code if you’d like to use it yourself.](http://www.julmar.com/samples/WatermarkPbox.zip)

Comment: He is using his own DLL and I can't use foreign dll in my bank's application. :(

Comment: Welcome Tuğrul Emre Atalay :)

Comment: I have a problem too Farhan, how can I give it's watermark property (CustomControls:PasswordBoxBehavior.Watermark="Enter Password...") in Resource.resw?

Like x:Uid="test.Watermark", but it is giving runtime error that Watermark property is not in PasswordBox.
I have changed it Test.MakePaymentAppBar.[using:Windows8.StoreApp.Common.CustomControls]PasswordBoxBehavior.Watermark   in Resource but it is not running.

Comment: I have a UserControl that has a StackPanel that has 2 watermarkpasswordbox. I am setting my watermarkpasswordboxes watermark values with “PasswordBoxBehavior.SetValue(mypwBox,”myvalue”);” under “InitializeComponent();” but watermarks don’t appear without focus-unfocus. Could you help me please? Why my watermarks don’t appear without focus, after unfocus it?

Comment: Set `IsTabStop="False"` in `<PasswordBox />`.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a watermark is to convey a message behind the control. In the case of this demonstration, the watermark also dissappear after you start typing text, so they are more like a field "hint" telling you what is expected.

To achieve this, we turn to a regular WPF solution provider, the AttachedProperty. AttachedProperties allow you to add extra properties to any control. You can also extend it into an Attachedbehaviour, where you are making the control react to changes to the property.

In this example, we use two attached properties. The first "WaterrmarkProperty" to take the watermark value and initialise the control:

```
public static string GetWatermark(DependencyObject obj) 
{ 
    return (string)obj.GetValue(WatermarkProperty); 
} 

public static void SetWatermark(DependencyObject obj, string value) 
{ 
    obj.SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value); 
} 

public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Watermark", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, WatermarkChanged));
```

The second attached property is to notify whether there is a value in the box, which the template binds to and hides or shows the watermark.

```
public static bool GetShowWatermark(DependencyObject obj) 
{ 
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(ShowWatermarkProperty); 
} 

public static void SetShowWatermark(DependencyObject obj, bool value) 
{ 
    obj.SetValue(ShowWatermarkProperty, value); 
} 

public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowWatermarkProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShowWatermark", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

For the TextBoxHelper, whenever the text is changed, the watermark is shown or hidden as follows:

```
private static void CheckShowWatermark(TextBox box) 
{ 
    box.SetValue(TextBoxHelper.ShowWatermarkProperty, box.Text == string.Empty); 
}
```

This is controlled by the ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WatermarkedTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"> 
    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"> 
        <Grid> 
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:TextBoxHelper.Watermark), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Opacity=".5" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding (local:TextBoxHelper.ShowWatermark), Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" /> 
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/> 
        </Grid> 
    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome> 
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"> 
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/> 
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/> 
        </Trigger> 
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

Source: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Watermarked-TextBox-and-444ebdec

Comment: I am trying it now, thank you. I will reply you after try it.

Comment: There is not a class named UIPropertyMetadata?

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: And have a look at this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585086/watermarked-passwordbox-in-winrt

Comment: Winrt :) I have looked them but all of them are not runnning. Only JulMar's code is running but he is using his own DLL and I can't use foreign dll in my bank's application.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8.0 you can use the [`WatermarkPasswordBox`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WatermarkPasswordBox/WatermarkPasswordBox.cs) from WinRT XAML Toolkit, which you can get from [here](http://nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit). It gives you a `Watermark` property to set any UI element (`Shape`, `Image`, etc.) as a watermark or `WatermarkText` property that takes a text and `WatermarkTextStyle` that takes a `TextBlock` `Style` to style the text.

In Windows 8.1 you can use the same or use the new [`PlaceholderText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.placeholdertext.aspx) property.

Feel free to rip out and modify the `WatermarkPasswordBox` control's code from the library and use it in your app. It's MIT licensed. No credits required. Just take the .cs and .xaml files and include the .xaml resource dictionary in your Themes/Generic.xaml like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary
        Source="ms-appx:///YourControlsLibraryNamefNotInMainApp/RelativeDirectoryPathOfTheFile/WatermarkPasswordBox.xaml" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Filip, I am waiting PlaceHolderText property :)